# Session disconnected loading a wep page

Tags: debian, session

On Ubuntu 22.04LTS, with dwm as window manager and lightdm as
session manager i get disconnected from my session when loading this web page https://github.com/philippnormann/xrandr-brightness-script

no experienced that with another web page for the moment

I do not have any idea why, do you?

Comment: if this wasn't just the not-very-problematic github standard interface, I'd guess a graphics card driver bug, or a browser bug that leads to dwm to segfault. But it's really a boring website. Can you check ~/.xsession-errors ?

Comment: I was not able to reproduce this error today. What i just did 
between was 'make install' on dwm and st folder.

Comment: .xsession-errors: dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DISPLAY=:0
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XAUTHORITY=/home/me/.Xauthority
/etc/X11/Xsession.d/30x11-common_xresources: ligne 16: has_option : commande introuvable
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
/etc/X11/Xsession.d/90x11-common_ssh-agent: ligne 9: has_option : commande introuvable
sh: 1: dwmblocks: not found